# Translate WebForms application in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, webforms, localization

I need to translate all text resources in all the .aspx files of a WebForms app with .NET 4 to have the option to switch language to english or spanish. This application uses DevExpress 14.2.

I have been searching for a library or an automated solution for this but I have not found anything useful.

I've tried the NopCommerce approach using WebScrapping to get all text resources from the .aspx pages and saving them in the DB as a dictionary with "key" and "value". Since NopCommerce use RazorPages to retrieve data from the DB using the controllers, I have no way to replicate that behaviour in the .aspx pages.

Translating all text resources from every .aspx page manually is not an option, since it would take too much time.

Have anyone translated a WebForms .NET 4 application? I am looking for suggestions and advice about this requirement.

Comment: Only suggestion is to take each page, take the text out, place in a database, and then have some function pull the text. With languages 1-6 as setting, then based on id + language you pull the text. Not much  different then using a resource file. Thus menus, buttons etc. have to be moved to a resource file, or I think better is a database. My suggesting is still translating of all text.  Having a "editor" for someone to then edit each record item, and enter the given language text means at least no developer time "once" that is done. However, this is not what you looking for.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thanks for the suggestion, that is what I think I will have to do, find a way to retrieve db data with ajax once the page is loaded and save all text resources in the DB using web scrapping

Comment: Not really sure I would add web methods, but simply load up the controls in a page load event. That way "one" routine could load the text assets for all controls etc. You can use a for-each on all the controls. Add a "tag" or even some made up attribute like "lang" to all the controls that have text to be changed. So, one routine call on load could make the required changes to the one page.